# Setting fixed scale of map in MapInfo layout?

Tags: mapinfo, scale

How do I set the scale of a map in MapInfo v16 64bit in a simple way?

I can zoom in and out using my mouse but I cannot find how to set the scale to say 1:1000 or 1:2000.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 5):

This is fairly easy to do in MapInfo (works in all versions).

1. Have your layer open in the map/layout window.
2. Right click anywhere on the map and select "Change View"
3. Change your Cartographic Scale to the value you want.